# While loop not working - Text adventure python game

Tags: python, python-3.x

My while loop is not working. I am trying to have it check to see if the player is dead or the enemy and if so the fight is over. If they are alive then fight again until someone is dead. With my code now even if one or both are dead the fight still goes on. I tried to make then if else statement and still does the same thing.

```
def fight():
  Monster.reduce_health(Player.weapon)
  Monster_check_dead()
  Player.reduce_health(Monster.damage)
  Player_check_dead()
  while Monster_check_dead == True or Player_check_dead == True:
    print ("Your fight is over")
    break
  else:
    fight_again()
```

Complete Code:

```
import random
import time

class Player:
  def __init__(self, name, weapon, health, armor):
    self.name = name
    self.weapon = weapon
    self.health = health
    self.armor = armor

  def reduce_health(self):
    Player.health = Player.health - Monster.damage


class Monster:
  def __init__(self, name, health, damage, armor):
    self.name = name
    self.health = health
    self.armor = armor
    self.damage = damage  

  def reduce_health(self):
    Monster.health = Monster.health - Player.weapon

def Monster_check_dead():
  if Monster.health < 1 == True :
    print(Monster.name, "has been killed")
  else:
    print (Monster.name, "current health: ", Monster.health)


def Player_check_dead():
  if Player.health < 1 == True :
    print(Player.name, "You have died")
  else:
    print (Player.name, "current health: ", Player.health)


def fight():
  Monster.reduce_health(Player.weapon)
  Monster_check_dead()
  Player.reduce_health(Monster.damage)
  Player_check_dead()
  while Monster_check_dead == True or Player_check_dead == True:
    print ("Your fight is over")
    break
  else:
    fight_again()

def fight_again():
  if ask("Do you wish to attack again"):
    fight()
  else:
    print ("You have ran away") 

def ask(question):
    answer = input(question + " [Y/N]")
    return answer in ["y", "Y", "Yes", "YES", "yes"]

print("Welcome to Nadia adventures the Nadia text adventure game!")

if ask("Do you wish to play the game?"):
    print ("Lets the great adventure start!")
    Player.name = "Nadia"
    Player.health = 100
    Player.weapon = 10
    Player.armor = 0
    print ("Nadia your current health is", Player.health)
time.sleep(1.0)

print("Nadia you have been teleported to a strange new world ....... ")

if ask("Do you wish to look around?"):
  print ("You start to look around and you have spotted a cave")
  ask("Do you wish to enter the cave?")
else: 
  print ("A gaint spider has appeared!")
  Monster.name = "Gaint spider"
  Monster.health = 25
  Monster.damage = 5
  if ask("Do you wish to fight?"):
    fight() 
  else:
    print("You have ran away")
```

Comment: your code is broken beyond repair, I'm afraid.

Comment: You want `if`, not `while`.. and yeah, other than that is what he said ^

Comment: `while Monster_check_dead == True or Player_check_dead == True:` is always false as you're comparing function objects to a boolean. You need to read more python resources like http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html

Comment: @EugeneSh. I did use If at first and it still did the same thing.

Comment: because there are several errors in your code. those functions return nothing, then you're testing the functions themselves, then there's this while/else (with break) loopy code... also stop testing against `== True`

Comment: your `ask` function returns nothing, so it's always "falsy". Read about functions & return values.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The reason I didn't include a return statement was that I originally did without adding a false return to the else part. I thought that the else statement would default to return false because the "if" statement was true. I didn't realize you need to return false until I saw the answer below. I assume that python would know.

Comment: if you don't return anything it's equivalent to `return None` (so almost `False`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell from your code, you just print out whether the monster or person is dead.

I would suggest making the Monster_Check_Dead and Person equivalent return True or False, as shown below.

```
def Monster_check_dead():
  if Monster.health < 1 == True :
    print(Monster.name, "has been killed")
    return True
  else:
    print (Monster.name, "current health: ", Monster.health)
    return False


def Player_check_dead():
  if Player.health < 1 == True :
    print(Player.name, "You have died")
    return True
  else:
    print (Player.name, "current health: ", Player.health)
    return False
```

Then in the first part of the code you showed, add parenthesis at the end of each of the methods

```
  while Monster_check_dead() or Player_check_dead():
    print ("Your fight is over")
    break
  else:
    fight_again()
```

If that doesn't work, inform me and I can re-look at what I did wrong.

Comment: while it 'fixes' some issues, I wouldn't avise to code like that.

Comment: @shodmoth it worked. I originally tried this without setting return False for the else statement. I thought that if I return True to the if statement, that the else would be false automatically without having me include return Flase in the code. Thanks

Comment: this code is horribly un-pythonic. And doesn't fix all the issues... For instance `while Monster_check_dead() == True or Player_check_dead() == True` should just be `while Monster_check_dead() or Player_check_dead()`, there are a lot of semicolons, this isn't C, they're useless. Comparing to `True` is redundant and shouldn't be done ...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks for the input. This is just my 2nd project in python and you have me thinking about cleaner code and not being redundant.

Comment: Sorry about the issues I added.  I was just programming in Java and totally forgot about python syntax.  I edited my answer to fix those issues.